# SSRS Data Driven Subscription that customizes DeviceInfo settings like PageWidth, PageHeight?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, png, ssrs-2012

I want to set up data driven subscriptions to mass output png files. The problem is that adding a new Extension for png in rsreportserver.config under Configurations/Extensions/Render only gives one fixed size of png file.

Report A really ought to output a 6in x 3in png file and report B ought to output a 6in x 4in png file.

Yes, I *could* create multiple entries in rsreportserver.config but this is confusing for end users as they show up on all users' export dropdowns needlessly.

I proposed doing the mass image generation with an external program that generates a custom url for each png (DeviceInfo settings *can* be part of the url) and uses WebClient.DownloadFile() in a loop, but my supervisor is currently really locked into the idea of data driven subscriptions for whatever reason.

Comment: Would exporting as `TIFF` and then converting post export work for you?

Comment: Probably not. Why? Does TIFF offer a way to customize page size per report?

Comment: The `TIFF` export follows the sizing you specify within the report, so if one report is `6x4` and another is `5x8`, those are the image dimensions you get, in the same way you can change the page size of a `word` or `pdf` export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @iamdave's suggestion, just setting the overarching page dimensions in report designer *does* give a suitably sized png file via data driven subscription without having to hardcode png dimensions in rsreportserver.config.

The reason I didn't initially notice this was the reports in question were graphs that were only ever used as subreports on an encompassing megareport and had never really been run as individual standalone reports. When used as a subreport, page dimensions never came into play, so they were left at the default 8.5x11.